# How to seperate longer stringvalues with tidyr into two columns

Tags: r, string, split, tidyr

When I try to seperate a column with (long) string values:

```
df <- tbl_df(c("Indian | Londen", "Greek | Amsterdam", "Hamburger and BBQ | Paris du Nord"))
df <- separate(df, col = value, into = c("var1","var2"), sep = " | ")
```

i get a warning message which says that there are too many values at three locations and when i look the altered dataframe i don't get the desired df

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
       var1  var2
*     <chr> <chr>
1    Indian     |
2     Greek     |
3 Hamburger   and
```

It seems to split at each space, does anyone know a way to work around this? var2 should contain the city or area name, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*separate* interpret `sep` parameter as regular expression when it is character. So you need to escape `|` which is a special character (*or*) in *regex*, pattern `|` (whitespace or whitespace) is the same as a whitespace in *regex*, which is why your strings are split by space:

```
df <- separate(df, col = value, into = c("var1","var2"), sep = " \\| ")

df
# A tibble: 3 × 2
#               var1          var2
#*             <chr>         <chr>
#1            Indian        Londen
#2             Greek     Amsterdam
#3 Hamburger and BBQ Paris du Nord
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do :

Since pipe has a special meaning in regex , it means "OR" ,hence you have to escape it first. you can also use it under character class `[|]` to get the same result

```
df1 <- separate(df, col = value, into = c("var1","var2"), sep = "\\|")
```

OR

```
df1 <- separate(df, col = value, into = c("var1","var2"), sep = "[|]")
```

**BASE R** way:

```
dfx<- data.frame(do.call("rbind",strsplit(df$value,split="\\|")))
```

Output:

```
> dfx
                  X1             X2
1            Indian          Londen
2             Greek       Amsterdam
3 Hamburger and BBQ   Paris du Nord
```